# Running into issues deserializing avro using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro library inside powershell

Tags: json, powershell, serialization, deserialization, avro

I am attempting to deserialize a binary avro file using the Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro library which can be found here.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization/

Instead of using the library inside a C# app I am actually using Powershell to attempt the deserialization.  Initially I import the Hadoop library as well as a dependent Newtonsoft.json library.  I do this by using the Add-Type cmdlet.  No problems with this at all.  The problem comes into play after I attempt to call the Deserialize method of the AvroSerializer class on a source avro filestream.  Here is a transcript of the call chain and the exception being returned when attempting to deserialize the avro filestream.

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20151230104411
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 5520
PSVersion: 5.0.10586.0
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0.10586.0
BuildVersion: 10.0.10586.0
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\mbird\Documents\PowerShell_transcript.BIRDSP3.eEl7IzKT.20151230104411.txt
PS C:\Users\mbird> $reader =  [Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.AvroSerializer]::CreateGeneric($json)
PS C:\Users\mbird> $fileStream =New-Object System.IO.FileStream("C:\Users\mbird\Downloads\created.avro",[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
PS C:\Users\mbird> $reader.Deserialize($fileStream)
Exception calling "Deserialize" with "1" argument(s): "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."
At line:1 char:1
+ $reader.Deserialize($fileStream)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OverflowException
Exception calling "Deserialize" with "1" argument(s): "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."
At line:1 char:1
+ $reader.Deserialize($fileStream)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OverflowException

PS C:\Users\mbird> Stop-Transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20151230104449
**********************
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.